# How to apply borders around each y axis label for Altair in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I have a visualization I made in Altair and I want to place borders around each label on the y axis (sorry if I am explaining this incorrectly) to separate them. This is the code I have so far:

```
alt.Chart(q4df).transform_fold(
  rosspaints,
  as_=['column', 'value']
).mark_circle().encode(
  x = alt.X('column:N', axis=None),
  y = alt.Y('TITLE', title=None),
  size = alt.Size('value:Q', legend=None),
  color=alt.Color('column:N', legend=None,
                   scale=alt.Scale(
            domain=['alizarin crimson','bright red','burnt umber','cadmium yellow','dark sienna', 
              'indian yellow','indian red','liquid black','liquid clear','black gesso',
              'midnight black','phthalo blue','phthalo green','prussian blue','sap green',
              'titanium white','van dyke brown','yellow ochre'],
            range=['#94261f','#c06341','#614f4b','#f8ed57','#5c2f08','#e6ba25','#cd5c5c',
                '#000000','#ffffff','#000000','#36373c','#2a64ad','#215c2c','#325fa3',
                '#364e00','#f9f7eb','#2d1a0c','#b28426']))

  
    
).properties(
    width=400,
    height=700
    
).configure_axis(grid=False, labelFontWeight= 'bold', labelColor='black')
```

This is my current output:

[image]

This is my desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either set a gridline for each y-axis tick like this:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data


source = data.barley()

alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    alt.X('yield:Q', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
    alt.Y('variety:N', axis=alt.Axis(grid=True)),
    color='year:N'
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
)
```

[image]

Or use facet according to the same variable you have encoded on the y-axis while resolving the y-scale so that only the y-axis entry with data points shows up in each plot:

```py
alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    alt.X('yield:Q', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
    alt.Y('variety:N', title=''),
    color='year:N',
).facet(
    row=alt.Facet('variety:N', title='', header=alt.Header(labels=False))
).resolve_scale(
    y='independent'
)
```

[image]